# image doesn't display in imageview in listitem (android)

Tags: android, listview, download, imageview

I'm new to android,i work on app . to download image and show it in list item .i used many functions for that . picasso and glide show nothing and third method i get this error

> "I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false"

so any suggestions to solve that. 
that is part of my code responsible for that

```
public class loader extends ArrayAdapter {

    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private String[] img;

    public loader(Context context, String[] img) {
        super(context, R.layout.item, img);

        this.context = context;
        this.img = img;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // ImageView imgshow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);

        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        //first method
        Glide.with(context)
               .load(img[position])
              .into(imageView);
        //second method
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview))
                .execute(img[position]);
        //third method
        Picasso.with(context).load(img[position]).into(imageView);

        return convertView;





    }
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }


}
```

i put that in my list by

```
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.updatelist);

    String[] img = new String[1000];
    loader im=new loader(mainpage.this,img);

    lv.setAdapter(im);
```

img[] is array of string contains url of images by using json

```
          try {

            // Load json data and display
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Content);
            //String responseString = json.getString("name");
            JSONArray jre = json.getJSONArray("updates");
            //HashMap<String, String> project = new HashMap<String, String>();


            for (int j = 0; j < jre.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject jobject = jre.getJSONObject(j);

                String name11 = jobject.getString("title");
                String description = jobject.getString("description");
                //String statu = jobject.getString("status");
                String image = jobject.getString("image");
                String total = url + image;
                img[j] = total;


                //projectname.setText(name11);
                //status.setText(description);
                //descrip.setText(statu);
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("title", name11);
                contact.put("description", description);
                contact.put(url+image,total);
                //contact.put("status", statu);
                contactList.add(contact);

            }
```

Comment: When is the last piece of code (the part that fills img[]) executed? From what I can see the array img[] seems to be created empty and immediately passed to the adapter.

Comment: i saved urls of image in array of strings after that i use loader class to display it in imageview in listitem

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your answer.

Comment: `Log` your image url is that correct? enter the image url in browser to check if image loads? Also is your image view visible?

Comment: i did that it is exist and my image view is visible